# Very slow query in ORDER BY with larger LIMIT range

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

MySQL 5.6, 64-bit, RHEL 5.8
A query on a large table with ORDER BY and LIMIT 'row_count' (or LIMIT 0,'row_count'). If the 'row_count' is larger then real count of result set, will be very very slow.

case 1: The query below is very fast (No 'LIMIT'):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM syslog WHERE 
        (ReportedTime BETWEEN '2013-11-04' AND '2013-11-05') AND
        Priority<3 AND Facility=1 ORDER BY id DESC;
+---
| ...
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

case 2: The query below is also fast ('LIMIT 5'):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM syslog WHERE 
        (ReportedTime BETWEEN '2013-11-04' AND '2013-11-05') AND
        Priority<3 AND Facility=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
+---
| ...
5 rows in set (0.42 sec)
```

case 3: The query below is very very slow ('LIMIT 7', may use any 'row_count' value > 6):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM syslog WHERE 
        (ReportedTime BETWEEN '2013-11-04' AND '2013-11-05') AND
        Priority<3 AND Facility=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7;
+---
| ...
6 rows in set (28 min 7.24 sec)
```

**Difference is just only individual (No LIMIT), "LIMIT 5", and "LIMIT 7".**
Why is case 3 so slow?
Some investigations in the case 3:

1. Run command 'SHOW PROCESS', the State of the query is kept in 'Sending data'

   - Checked the server memory, it's still available enough.
   - Extended SESSION buffers 'read_buffer_size','read_rnd_buffer_size','sort_buffer_size' to very large amount (to 16MB) right before running query, but no help.
   - Also query only the column 'id' (`SELECT id FROM syslog ....`), but the same result.
2. During the query is running, raised the same query but with row_count<5 (eg. 'LIMIT 5') in another mysql connection, the return of latter is still very soon.
3. With different condition, for example, extend the time range `BETWEEN '2013-10-03' to '2013-11-05'` to gain result row count **149**. With `LIMIT 140`, it's fast. With `LIMIT 150`, it's very very slow. So strange.

Currently in practice, in our website, the program gets the real result row count first (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`, No ORDER BY, No LIMIT), and afterwards do the query with the LIMIT 'row_count' value not exceeding the real row count got just now. Ugly.

The EXPLAIN for case 3:

```
-+-----..-+----..+-------+-----..+--------+---------+-----+-----+------------+
 | sele.. | table| type  | poss..| key    | key_len | ref | rows| Extra      |
-+-----..-+----..+-------+-----..+--------+---------+-----+-----+------------+
 | SIMPLE | syslo| index | ...   | PRIMARY| 8       | NULL| 132 | Using where|
-+-----..-+----..+-------+-----..+--------+---------+-----+-----+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE syslog (
    id          BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ReceivedAt  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ReportedTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    Priority    SMALLINT,
    Facility    SMALLINT,
    FromHost    VARCHAR(60),
    Message     TEXT,
    InfoUnitID  INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    SysLogTag   VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY idx_ReportedTime_Priority_id (ReportedTime,Priority,id),
    KEY idx_Facility (Facility),
    KEY idx_SysLogTag (SysLogTag(16)),
    KEY idx_FromHost (FromHost(16))
);
```

Comment: Have you tried putting an index on `Facility` as well? Is this InnoDB or MyISAM or even something else like Archive?

Comment: Show us the explain plan of the query which is taking more time

Comment: The main issue here, if the index would affect the query, the first and second case should also slow. right? The huge performance differences just between LIMIT 6(fast) and LIMIT 7(very slow).

Comment: The EXPLAIN says it used PRIMARY key only

Comment: I tried in both InnoDB and MyISAM. Got the same issue.

Comment: `+-------... +---------+---------+------+------+-------------+`
`| possib... | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |`
`+-------... +---------+---------+------+------+-------------+`  
`| ...       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |  132 | Using where |`
`+-------... +---------+---------+------+------+-------------+`
`1 rows in set (0.00 sec)`
You may see, even use Primary key, the rows is only 132

Comment: Execute `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM syslog WHERE (ReportedTime BETWEEN '2013-11-04' AND '2013-11-05') AND Priority<3 AND Facility=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7;` and update the your answer with the result

Comment: To me it is not query or DB structure problem but, can be low RAM, broken index, slow Harddisk, busy server otherwise, the list is long, but does this happen with this table only? If so, maybe you should drop this table and recreate it... or try to optimize the table first.

Comment: @ChanceHsu Your last record is returning a huge data which is keeping your system in 'Sending data' state and taking too much time to return results. To confirm this SELECT only id column. 
Is there any TEXT column? Please show your complete table structure.

Comment: please give us the index description. (name and columns)

Comment: I have provided the complete table/index definition, and with more investigations.

Comment: @ChanceHsu thank you. Would you mind extracting the explain plan of the 1st query please?

Comment: @Sebas, EXPLAIN the case 1, it uses KEY Facility.  EXPLAIN the case 3, it uses KEY Primary. I add FORCE INDEX, the problem seems solved. Thank you and everybody giving help so much.

Comment: @ChanceHsu Ok. I'd appreciate if you marked my answer then, please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mysql is famous for its behaviour around `ORDER BY DESC + LIMIT`  clause.

See: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Please try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM syslog FORCE INDEX (Facility)
WHERE 
    ReportedTime BETWEEN '2013-11-04' AND '2013-11-05' 
AND Priority<3 
AND Facility=1 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 7;
```

You need to force the use of the index used in first queries. (get it from their explain plans, KEY column)

Comment: I add `FORCE INDEX (idx_ReportedTime_Priority_id)`. It becomes normal and very soon. I don't know MySQL's inner and why from `LIMIT 5` to `LIMIT 6` would be different so much though. Thank you very much.